# Read ID from URL and create a new one

Tags: c#, asp.net

On Page_Load, I have to run code to check a url format. The url can be of the following formats:

```
http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID=230  or

http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID=230&blahblah or

http://www.xyzabc.com/S(yya4h4rf4gjh5eo4uazix2t055)X(1))/DisplayProduct?ID=230
```

Whenever the url has an ID, I want to create a url in the following format:

```
http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID=<the id picked from the url>
```

Since the code will be run for every page (1500+) in the site, how can i write the best optimized code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
int ID = 0;

int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out ID);

if (ID > 0)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID={0}", ID));
}
```

Comment: TryParse returns a boolean is successful. So you code should be `if(int.TryParse(..., out ID))`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `URLRouting` or make use of `HTTPHandler/HTTPModule` if possible............

here is link on msdn for this : [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by creating custom httpmodule to handle request and rewrite url

see this [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx#urlrewriting_topic4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpModules for this, by using

```
context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
```

and in context_BeginRequest you do something like:

```
context.Response.Redirect(..)
```

This would be somewhat very "raw" solution, where you have multiple URL rewriting engines for ASP.NET, just check the Internet / SO for these....

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.Redirect("http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: If I use this code, wouldn't I be getting '230&blahblah' for a url like this http://www.xyzabc.com/DisplayProduct?ID=230&blahblah

Answer (score 0):

Use URL Rewriting Libaray and configure it in web.config to avoid extra code.